# Symbolic link catch user input

Tags: bash, symlink

I want to create a symbolic link with the name `xyz`, and then catch the input the user gives including the symbolic link name.

Example: If the user types:

```
xyz load aab\1.0.5
```

I want to have `xyz load aab\1.0.5` as a string that I can do more stuff with.

Why do I ask? (things you can skip reading)

In this case I will compare parts of this string with the names of directories and either

1. give the user a warning if there is no match, or
2. execute the command as it otherwise would.

What I want to do is to hijack the `module` command.

Edit: I suppose I should be using alias.

Edit2: Clarification

The exact thing I want to do is this: when a user types `module load program` or `module load program/2.3.3`. I don't want the command to execute before I know if the version they are requesting is available for the specific platform. I can check what versions are available by looking in the folder `/app/firefox/.sys/@sys/`.

The underlying "problem" is that `module` is set up in a way that makes all modules available for SLES 10 and 11 and 32bit and 64bit so in some cases users try to load a version that is not available on their platform.

I have now realized a problem: if they do not type version, then it will pick the default version. But I don't know how to easily find out the default version using a script. grepping `module appname avail` to get the version that has "(default)" in it does not work since it is something else then module that are printing the result. For example `module firefox avail >> result.text` gives an empty file.

Comment: What is the question? What do you want the link to point to? Please, be more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I get the question right, but may be you're trying to 'hook' a specific command/s. In that case, you could do it using a hook script, and links to it with the same name as the commands you want to hook, that appear in the $PATH before the real ones, so you can decide to call or not the real commands.

For example:

(Warning: this is another *dangerous and ugly hack*)

$cat hook

```
#!/bin/bash
# hook for some commands

echo $0

cmd=$(basename "$0")
echo "called as $cmd"

if [[ $cmd = "module" ]]
then
    realcmd=/usr/bin/module

    # verify parameters

    # then call real command
    $realcmd "$@"
    rc=$?
    exit $rc
else
    echo "???" 1>&2
    exit 1
fi
```

$chmod a+x hook

$ln -s hook module

$PATH=.:$PATH module arg1 arg2

Comment: Thanks, this helped me to get to the next step. No up vote due to low reputation.

Comment: You're very welcome. You can also mark an answer as the accepted one, if so decided (http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)